# Calcular un plazo dado una fecha de inicio y una cantidad de dias - Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, date, datetime

Mi principal problema esta en el while, por ejemplo digamos que la fecha de inicio que se ingresa es 08/05/2020(Viernes) y la cantidad de días es de 2, una vez que entra la función el día 08/05/2020 es valido así ya que no es feriado ni es sábado o domingo, se le suma un día y ve el siguiente día para ver si puede terminar de calcular el plazo pero no puede porque los dos días que le siguen son sábado y domingo, ahora tiene que calcular el día 11/05/2020(Lunes) pero es feriado y se tendría que saltear ese día para poder ver si el siguiente día es valido para terminar de calcular el plazo pero antes de verificar el día feriado se termina el while, que me recomiendan cambiar en el while para que funcione correctamente?

Los métodos que uso en el if que están dentro de el while funcionan de 10, mi problema es con el maldito whileee :(

Gracias:)

```
public Evento crearPlazo(DateTime fechaInicio, Integer cantDias, String tipoPlazo, Evento evento, Usuario usuario,
        TipoDiaNoLaborable tipoDiaNoLaborable) throws ParseException {

    DateTime fechaActual = fechaInicio;
    DateTime fechaWhile = fechaInicio;
    HashSet<DateTime> diasNoLaborales  = buscarDiasNoLaborales(usuario, tipoDiaNoLaborable);

    Integer i = 0;
    int y = cantDias;
    while (i <= cantDias) {
        if (validarFinDeSemana(fechaWhile) == false && validarFechaActual(diasNoLaborales, fechaWhile) == false) {
            fechaWhile = fechaWhile.plusDays(1);
            i++;
        } else {
            fechaWhile = fechaWhile.plusDays(1);
            y++;
            i++;
        }

    }
    fechaActual = fechaActual.plusDays(y - 1);
    DateTime fechaFinal = fechaActual;

    evento.setTipoPlazo(TipoPlazo.DIAS_HABILES);
    evento.setTipoDiaNoLaborable(tipoDiaNoLaborable);
    evento.setFechaInicio(fechaInicio.toDate());
    evento.setFechaFin(fechaFinal.toDate());
    evento.setCantDias(cantDias);

    return evento;

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Probaste debuguear el codigo y ver los valores que van tomando las variables para ver porque no termina nunca?

Comment: Hola, perdón ahí lo corregí un poco, el while si termina no entra en un loop infinito

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar.. probaste debuguear?? porque la condicion de cierre es simple, e i siempre va aumentando por lo que salvo que cantdias sea infinito, en algun momento deberia terminar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que con la condición que tiene tu while, solo se ejecutará según el valor de cantDias (en tu caso 2), por eso nunca llega al lunes.
Creo que tu intención era cambiar el valor de cantDias para que el while siga ciclando, pero en lugar de eso, incrementas **y** que no se usa en ningún lado.
Creo que así podría funcionar (no lo he probado):

```
while (i <= cantDias) {
    if (validarFinDeSemana(fechaWhile) && validarFechaActual(diasNoLaborales, fechaWhile)) {
        i++
    } 
    fechaWhile = fechaWhile.plusDays(1);
}
```

Es decir, solo incrementas tu contador de días, si es un día laborable, si no no lo haces y sigues buscando el día laborable.

Comment: Te recomendaría además que a tus funciones les pongas un nombre más claro, por ejemplo esFinDeSemana() o esDiaNoLaboral(), porque con el nombre actual, no sé cuál es el resultado  que debo esperar en caso de pasar o no la validación.